# Setting Combobox Height OwnerDrawVariable ( Unexpected display result )

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, drawing, controls

First of all, i did make a combox box with ownerdrawvariable mod because i wanted to handle a tooltips with the mouse hover. To do this i handled two methods DrawItem and MeasureItem :

```
    Private Sub DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboPneuGlobal.DrawItem

    If e.Index = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    e.DrawBackground()

    Dim p As Point = New Point(CInt(cboPneuGlobal.Location.X * Ratio), CInt(cboPneuGlobal.Location.Y * Ratio))
    Dim brColor As Brush = Brushes.Black

    If e.State = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        ToolTipFormBase.Show(CType(cboPneuGlobal.Items(e.Index), clsPneuEtTypeMarque).ToDisplay, Me, p)
        brColor = Brushes.White
    End If


    e.Graphics.DrawString(CType(cboPneuGlobal.Items(e.Index), clsPneuEtTypeMarque).ToDisplay, e.Font, brColor, New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))

End Sub
```

Here the second :

```
    Private Sub measureItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs) Handles cboPneuGlobal.MeasureItem

    ' fetch the current item we’re painting as specified by the index
    Dim comboBoxItem As Object = cboPneuGlobal.Items(e.Index)

    ' measure the text of the item (in Whidbey consider using TextRenderer.MeasureText instead)
    Dim textSize As Size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(CType(cboPneuGlobal.Items(e.Index), clsPneuEtTypeMarque).ToDisplay, cboPneuGlobal.Font).ToSize()
    e.ItemHeight = textSize.Height
    e.ItemWidth = textSize.Width

End Sub
```

I got a small display problem which the combo box height doesn't follow the font of my item and stay small. That make my text truncate. See the image :

[image: Image1]

[image]

What i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: We just don't use visual theme for the application. It's work great with a non ownerdraw combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work great with a non ownerdraw combobox